# Clang - "unable to execute command: program not executable"

Tags: c++, c, windows, clang

I'm trying to compile this code:

```
extern "C" void __declspec(dllexport)  TEST(int num)
{
    return;
}
```

With this command line:

```
clang++ main.cpp -shared -o test.dll
```

and clang is failing to (it appears, anyway) find the linker

Verbose output from clang:

> "g++" -shared -v -c -m32 -o "C:\Users\Steve\AppData\Local\Temp\main-c7cf26.o" -x assembler "C:\Users\Steve\AppData\Local\Temp\main-5132f2.s"
>    clang++.exe: error: unable to execute command: program not executable
>    "g++" -shared -v -c -m32 -o "C:\Users\Steve\AppData\Local\Temp\TEST_CLANG-e037c5.o" -x assembler "C:\Users\Steve\Documents\A\codeblox\TEST_CLANG\TEST_CLANG.s"
>    clang++.exe: error: unable to execute command: program not executable

So it looks like clang is unable to find g++, but my PATH is set to:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\LLVM\bin>%PATH%
'"C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin"'
```

So I'm not really understanding that the issue is here!

Comment: Nevermind, it's because I had quotes in the PATH variable.